# Get simple name for the running application

Tags: java, android

How can i make my code to show only the name of running application which i can kill, because in my code it show the package name and that is very confusing for the user. And also, i want it to have an icon beside the application so that the user will identify it easily. i got this code from the internet and i used it for my project. Here is my code:

```
    private List<TaskObject> getTasksToKill() {
        List<TaskObject> tol = new ArrayList<TaskObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            TaskObject to = adapter.getItem(i);
            if (to.isToKill()) {
                tol.add(to);
            }
        }

        return tol;
    }


    public void loadRunningProcesses() {

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appinfolist = activityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();

        Log.d(TAG, "AppInfoList Size: " + appinfolist.size());

        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : appinfolist) {
            TaskObject runningtask = new TaskObject();
            runningtask.setPid(runningAppProcessInfo.pid);
            runningtask.setProcessName(runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
            adapter.addTask(runningtask);
        }
    }

    class TaskObject {
        int pid;
        String processName;
        private boolean toKill;

        public int getPid() {
            return pid;
        }

        public void setPid(int pid) {
            this.pid = pid;
        }

        public String getProcessName() {
            return processName;
        }

        public void setProcessName(String processName) {
            this.processName = processName;
        }

        public boolean isToKill() {
            return toKill;
        }

        public void setToKill(boolean toKill) {
            this.toKill = toKill;
        }

    }

    }
}
```

Hoping for all of your answers and recommendation. Thank you for all of your help :)

Comment: To make it easier for people to answer your question, please cut out irrelevant code, just post whatever is relevant to the question.

Comment: I edited it already I'm sorry the irrelevant code :)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure how to do this in pure Java, but in native code you can call the POSIX [kill(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) function. If you pass 0 for the signal ID, no signal is sent to the process, but it still does the privilege checks to see whether you can control that process. Basically do this for every process, and only show a list of those processes for which you got back no error.

Comment: Pseudocode: for (thispid in each process id) { if (kill(thispid, 0) == 0) {I can affect thispid} }

Comment: sir is this for getting the simple name of running application. because in my code I'm getting the package name of application for example: _com.android.music_ what i want is the _music_ only that is easy to read. :)))